# Why is the phase of the reflected light important in the Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) experiment?

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-entanglement, refraction

Trying to understand the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect)) I got a bit lost with regards to what the reflection phases mean for the experiment and the kind of beam splitter required.

Instead of single photons, let's say that there are two coherent beams (A and B) and a beam splitter plate with a dielectric coating on the bottom (as suggested from Wikipedia link). Beam A is reaching the beam splitter from above, beam B from below. If beam A is reflected or refracted, there is no phase shift. If beam B gets reflected it gets a phase of $\pi$, and a phase of $0$ if transmitted.

We have four possibilities:
[image]

1. Beam A gets reflected and beam B is transmitted. In that case none of the beams gets a relative phase and both beams constructively interfere.
2. Beam A and B get transmitted. Nothing interesting happens, the beams just exchanged sides.
3. Beams A and B are reflected off the beam splitter. Nothing interesting happens, each went back their way. With the caveat that beam B obtains a relative phase of $\pi$.
4. Beam A is transmitted and beam B gets reflected. This case is confusing me, as beam A goes through the beam splitter, no phase added, and beam B gets reflected with a phase of $\pi$. So in principle the beams cancel as they interfere destructively.

In the Hong-Ou-Mandel experiment, only (1) and (4) contribute, while (2) and (3) cancel out. But that's not what I am getting by looking at the phases. Note that, if (2) and (3) indeed cancel out, the beams should still interfere destructively in (4), so (1) would be the only possible result.

Another possibility is that the beam splitter in this experiment is some kind of symmetrical cube beam splitter, where the reflective surface is inside a crystal. In that case no relative phase is gained by the outgoing beams, but then it is even more difficult to see why relative phases from reflection matter here.

What am I missing in this setup? What can be understood from the nature of the beam splitter and the phases of reflection? Can this effect only be understood using second quantization and the reflection phases do not matter here?

Comment: You could label your cases 3, 2, 1, 4 to match the diagram in the linked page (which you can insert in your question), and labeled them 1, 2, 3, 4 so there is not a proliferation of a, A, b, B, c, d. Also, preserving the order in the diagram helps. It makes analyzing it _much_ easier.

Comment: It's a quantum mechanical phenomenon. Trying to understand it from a classical perspective will not work.

Comment: @josephh so do you agree that the phase from reflection is not important?

Comment: @JEB somebody edited my post and added that link. It was not there to begin with, but I have followed your suggestion.

Comment: Your $\tau'$ matrix does not seem to represent a unitary matrix.

Comment: @flippiefanus check again, I find the determinant to be $-1$

Comment: To be unitary, the Hermitian adjoint of a matrix must be equal to its inverse. It does not seem to be the case for $\tau'$.

Comment: @flippiefanus it is unitary, what am I writing wrong? see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2+%7B%7Bexp%28i+a%29%2C+exp%28-i+b%29%7D%2C%7Bexp%28i+b%29%2C+-exp%28-i+a%29%7D%7D.+%7B%7Bexp%28-i+a%29%2C+exp%28-i+b%29%7D%2C%7Bexp%28i+b%29%2C+-exp%28i+a%29%7D%7D

Comment: OK you are right. I did it in my head and then got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the reflection phases of a beam splitter do not matter as long as it is a 50%-50% transmission/reflection beam splitter.

flippiefanus provides some insight in why we cannot consider this as a classical effect. As a direct answer to this question, I will post my own calculation.

The answers to this are in the Wikipedia article as it says clearly that the classical result is different from the quantum one. It is just a bit misleading about why it discusses the reflection phase of a particular beam splitter.

### Classical calculation

Note that the equation for a beam splitter is just
$$(O_A,O_B)=\tau (I_A,I_B)$$
where $I_A$ and $I_B$ are the incoming outputs from beams A and B, $\tau$ is the transfer matrix and $O_a$ and $O_B$ are the output beams in the directions A and B, respectively. The transfer matrix $\tau$ is a unitary be it quantum or classical description as the beam splitter behaves the same backwards per Helmholtz reciprocity theorem.

For a plate dielectric beam splitter as described first above, we have
$$\tau_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

that means that if $(I_A,I_B)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$ then the output is $(O_A,O_B)=(1,0)$, meaning that all of the emitted light is in one direction (A). This is expected due to unitarity, as a single beam will split into two, a symmetrical input of two beams will converge into 1. Note that the results vary if we have a more general beam splitter,

$$\tau=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\phi_R}& e^{-i\phi_T}\\ e^{i\phi_T} & -e^{-i\phi_R}\end{pmatrix}$$.

(where $\phi_R$ and $\phi_T$ are phases of reflection/tranmission) as $\tau (I_A,I_B)= \frac{1}{2}( e^{i\phi_R}+ e^{-i\phi_T}, e^{-i\phi_R}+ e^{i\phi_T})$.

So do the $\phi_R,\phi_T$ influence the HOM experiment?

### Quantum calculation

As suggested, the only way to find out is to carry out the quantum calculation.

Let the input state be $|1_A,1_B\rangle=a^\dagger b^\dagger|0_A,0_B \rangle$, where $a^\dagger$ and $b^\dagger$ are bosonic creation operations in channels A and B, and $|n_A,n_B\rangle$ correspond to a state with $n_A$ and $n_B$ photons in channels A and B.

The state is modified by $\tau$, such that the output state is given by $c^\dagger d^\dagger |0_A,0_B\rangle$, where

$$\begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger \\ d^\dagger\end{pmatrix}=\tau \begin{pmatrix} a^\dagger \\ b^\dagger\end{pmatrix}$$

thus the output is given by

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(a^\dagger e^{i\phi_R}+b^\dagger e^{-i\phi_T})\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(a^\dagger e^{i\phi_T}-b^\dagger e^{-i\phi_R})|0_A,0_B\rangle=\frac{1}{2}[((a^\dagger)^2 e^{i(\phi_R+\phi_T)}-(b^\dagger)^2 e^{-i(\phi_T+\phi_R)}+a^\dagger b^\dagger (1-1)]|0_A,0_B\rangle= \frac{1}{2}([(a^\dagger)^2 e^{i(\phi_R+\phi_T)}-(b^\dagger)^2 e^{-i(\phi_T+\phi_R)}]|0_A,0_B\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(e^{i(\phi_R+\phi_T)}|2_A,0_B\rangle-e^{-i(\phi_R+\phi_T)}|0_A,2_B\rangle)
$$

So in general, the output has no crossed term of the type $a^\dagger b^\dagger$ to create a state with one photon in each channel $|1_A,1_B\rangle$ (this would be the case as long as the unitary matrix $\tau$ has permanent $0$). Also there is no way to find a beam splitter that can cancel the output of one of the channels as in the classical result with light beams.

Answer (score 0):

The experiment does not work with beams of light (like in the classical case). It needs to be single photons, because this is a quantum multi-particle interference effect. The phases (or phase-changes) are very important. The process needs to be unitary. Without the correct phases-changes the process won't be unitary. However, there are different ways to represent the unitary process. One can, for example, multiply the two input photons with arbitrary phases and do the same for the two output photons. Nevertheless, such changes do not change the interference effect (only the details of the states).

Note that this is a multi-photon interference effect, which is different from ordinary optical interference. The latter is the result of the superposition of two beam in which the same photon appears. So it is of the form
$$ |\phi_a\rangle + |\phi_b\rangle . $$
In the multi photon case, like in HOM, the interference is a superposition of multiple photons:
$$ |\phi_a\rangle|\psi_a\rangle| + |\phi_b\rangle|\psi_b\rangle . $$
As a result, it does not produce the same interference effect that we are familiar with from ordinary optical interference. In optical interference "every photon only interferes with itself". That is not the case with multi-photon scenarios.

About the phases, one can always multiply the output photons after the beamsplitter by separate local phase factors without affecting the detections of photons. The same can be done for the input photons, but that could affect the synchronization of the photons, which in turn affects location of the HOM dip. Nevertheless, the affect of these local phase modulations allow a variety of different but equivalent ways to define the unitary matrix for the beamsplitter, all of which produce the same multi-photon interference effect associated with the HOM effect.

Comment: I get that this is a quantum effect and that the operators need unitarity and thus the signs. However by looking at the effect on classical experiment it is not clear what is the correspondence with the expected quantum output. Note that you could say that (2) and (3) do cancel out because incoming photons get out with opposite phases. But that does not explain why there is no destructive interference in (4). Also do you agree then where the reflecting surface is located (inside or in the surface of the beam splitter) is not important?

Comment: I'll add something about that.

Comment: Could you say a word or two on the nature of the beam splitter? What kind of beam splitter is needed here?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by the *kind* of beam splitter. A beam splitter used in optics is a optical component made of glass with the property that it can separate an optical beam into two beams. When the optical beam entering such an optical component is a quantum state (like a single photon state), the beamsplitter is represented by a unitary operation.

Comment: There are different kinds of beam splitter. For a 50%/50% beam splitter, it can for example be symmetrical cube or asymmetrical plates (as indicated above) as in a Mach-Zehnder interferometer. The phases of the outputs are different in each case. How does that affect the HOM experiment? maybe it just does not.

Comment: I've added a bit about the phases. As for the Wikipedia page, it does state that the HOM effect cannot be explained with the aid of classical optics. So I do not think that their explanation is "without QM." It is indeed necessary to use QM to understand the HOM effect.

Comment: @Mauricio the kind of beam splitter is irrelevant here.  In fact, the phases $e^{i\varphi_k}$ that you have are also irrelevant provided there is one relative minus sign *somewhere*.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero try to carry out the quantum calculation, the HOM effect would not provide the usual result (zero coincidence between both output channels) for certain phase configurations.

Comment: @Mauricio I can do the quantum calculation in my sleep:  the coincidence rate is related to the permanent of the matrix describing the beamsplitter.  This permanent is $0$ if the minus sign in your $\tau$ is anywhere, assuming your $\tau$ is unitary (which restricts the possible phases but is otherwise independent of these phases).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero so do you agree that looking at the reflection phases of the beam splitter as Wikipedia does in the "physical description" part is misleading?

Comment: well i’m not sure where your issue is.  Clearly on graphs 2 and 3 have amplitudes that will contribute to the rates since 1 and 4 are selected out by requiring 1 photon in each output port.

Comment: There’s this nice (detailed) pedagogical discussion at the quantum level: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00080

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am talking about phrases like this in the article "reflection from the bottom side of the beam splitter introduces a relative phase shift of π, corresponding to a factor of −1 in the associated term in the superposition" which is irrelevant for the quantum version, or at least it should say  somewhere that is an example of a beam splitter or that it works for any kind of beam splitter..